# GuzzleHttp exception on drupal console commands

Tags: ssl, curl, guzzle

On various drupal console commands i made ( new site, download module ) , i get a GuzzleHttp exception

```
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]                                      
  cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not experiencing an issue with Drupal.

SSL certificate validation is failing.

More info on what to do within Guzzle can be found within the documentation on [Request Options - Verify](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/request-options.html#verify).  Additional information on SSL certificates can be found [cURL Documentation - SSL Certificates](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)